# Total Contacts Count not coming on all mailing page

Tags: gui-extensions, outbound-email, tracking

We have enabled outbound email tracking for newsletter email.But on all mailing screen total contacts column does'nt show any value[image].

I have gone through the documentation of Outbound email and Audience manager, and could not able to find out any solution for this issue.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated. Please let me know if I am missing any documentation or tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like other statistics, the Total Contacts column is only updated when you click the Refresh Statistics button or context menu option. This is for performance reasons.

That said, the Total Contacts column is only relevant for Distribution Lists and Address Books. It's present because you can have both Mailings and Distribution Lists within the same Folder.

This is covered on the following documentation page:
[Refreshing statistics](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-90344BCB-5819-4FDB-A2E4-4D04D6EB7018)